# how to access the following json in php I am accessing following way

Tags: php

[data base pic that containd duplicate values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K05Ge.png)This Is my JSON half i have posted

```
 {
    "gstin": "29AAHCS4690J1ZQ",
    "fp": "072017",
    "b2b": [{
            "ctin": "01AAACJ4126D1ZE",
            "cfs": "Y",
            "inv": [{
                "itms": [{
                    "num": 1,
                    "itc": {
                        "tx_cs": 0,
                        "elg": "ip",
                        "tx_i": 112.5
                    },
                    "itm_det": {
                        "csamt": 0,
                        "rt": 18,
                        "txval": 625,
                        "iamt": 112.5
                    }
                }],
                "val": 738,
                "inv_typ": "R",
                "flag": "N",
                "updby": "S",
                "pos": "29",
                "idt": "31-07-2017",
                "rchrg": "N",
                "cflag": "U",
                "inum": "FL-17000069",
                "chksum": "4d3e41facf5002f418e1ac605d9888d74ee21652e19de6db624fc7106e3c5866"
            }]
        },


        {
            "ctin": "29AACFI3027K1ZC",
            "cfs": "Y",
            "inv": [{
                "itms": [{
                    "num": 1800,
                    "itc": {
                        "elg": "ip",
                        "tx_c": 171.59,
                        "tx_s": 171.59
                    },
                    "itm_det": {
                        "samt": 171.59,
                        "rt": 18,
                        "txval": 1906.5,
                        "camt": 171.59
                    }
                }],
                "val": 2250,
                "inv_typ": "R",
                "flag": "N",
                "updby": "S",
                "pos": "29",
                "idt": "06-07-2017",
                "rchrg": "Y",
                "cflag": "U",
                "inum": "0042",
                "chksum": "aa1187a2bb7d6098c39c4c992bd391ab7fd59e7eeefcea5b91fc9881ba4423d8"
            }]
        },
        {
            "ctin": "29AAACT7966R2Z6",
            "cfs": "Y",
            "inv": [{
                    "itms": [{
                        "num": 1,
                        "itc": {
                            "elg": "ip",
                            "tx_c": 20,
                            "tx_s": 20
                        },
                        "itm_det": {
                            "samt": 20,
                            "rt": 5,
                            "txval": 800,
                            "camt": 20
                        }
                    }],
                    "val": 800,
                    "inv_typ": "R",
                    "flag": "N",
                    "updby": "S",
                    "pos": "29",
                    "idt": "06-07-2017",
                    "rchrg": "Y",
                    "cflag": "U",
                    "inum": "507002834",
                    "chksum": "64b19ecd192545bcfeac89f9ef7e30965122d5159be6a66d4c7888a8b6e1b6ae"
                },
                {
                    "itms": [{
                        "num": 1,
                        "itc": {
                            "elg": "ip",
                            "tx_c": 20.38,
                            "tx_s": 20.38
                        },
                        "itm_det": {
                            "samt": 20.38,
                            "rt": 5,
                            "txval": 815,
                            "camt": 20.38
                        }
                    }],
                    "val": 815,
                    "inv_typ": "R",
                    "flag": "N",
                    "updby": "S",
                    "pos": "29",
                    "idt": "26-07-2017",
                    "rchrg": "Y",
                    "cflag": "U",
                    "inum": "507015095",
                    "chksum": "c76544937d5f7b8513bb64d45ba5708ff4f67197652b6ba06a605931b7ce58b6"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "ctin": "29AACCM4309H1ZI",
            "cfs": "Y",
            "inv": [{
                    "itms": [{
                        "num": 1,
                        "itc": {
                            "tx_cs": 0,
                            "elg": "ip",
                            "tx_c": 329,
                            "tx_s": 329
                        },
                        "itm_det": {
                            "samt": 329,
                            "csamt": 0,
                            "rt": 28,
                            "txval": 2350,
                            "camt": 329
                        }
                    }],
                    "val": 3008,
                    "inv_typ": "R",
                    "flag": "N",
                    "updby": "S",
                    "pos": "29",
                    "idt": "11-07-2017",
                    "rchrg": "N",
                    "cflag": "U",
                    "inum": "021/RS/17000016",
                    "chksum": "096e525d241d942cdf7695976d1dfc0ada181ab01d85dc6d6506d4865983a491"
                },
                {
                    "itms": [{
                        "num": 1,
                        "itc": {
                            "tx_cs": 0,
                            "elg": "ip",
                            "tx_c": 452.38,
                            "tx_s": 452.38
                        },
                        "itm_det": {
                            "samt": 452.38,
                            "csamt": 0,
                            "rt": 28,
                            "txval": 3231.25,
                            "camt": 452.38
                        }
                    }],
                    "val": 4136.01,
                    "inv_typ": "R",
                    "flag": "N",
                    "updby": "S",
                    "pos": "29",
                    "idt": "21-07-2017",
                    "rchrg": "N",
                    "cflag": "U",
                    "inum": "021/RS/17000026",
                    "chksum": "196ff72d3507ea9fe69448cce2df27f9f3bf6ef05c2b691e47f245cb10f53747"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "ctin": "29ABRPH6549P1ZK",
            "cfs": "Y",
            "inv": [{
                    "itms": [{
                        "num": 1800,
                        "itc": {
                            "elg": "ip",
                            "tx_c": 114.39,
                            "tx_s": 114.39
                        },
                        "itm_det": {
                            "samt": 114.39,
                            "rt": 18,
                            "txval": 1271,
                            "camt": 114.39
                        }
                    }],
                    "val": 1500,
                    "inv_typ": "R",
                    "flag": "N",
                    "updby": "S",
                    "pos": "29",
                    "idt": "31-07-2017",
                    "rchrg": "N",
                    "cflag": "U",
                    "inum": "10",
                    "chksum": "5e2c5b651c027f5707fddd422de3301e71d3a713169c9de00da7de688742b030"
                },
                {
                    "itms": [{
                            "num": 500,
                            "itc": {
                                "elg": "ip",
                                "tx_c": 132.5,
                                "tx_s": 132.5
                            },
                            "itm_det": {
                                "samt": 132.5,
                                "rt": 5,
                                "txval": 5300,
                                "camt": 132.5
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "num": 1200,
                            "itc": {
                                "elg": "ip",
                                "tx_c": 24,
                                "tx_s": 24
                            },
                            "itm_det": {
                                "samt": 24,
                                "rt": 12,
                                "txval": 400,
                                "camt": 24
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "val": 6013,
                    "inv_typ": "R",
                    "flag": "N",
                    "updby": "S",
                    "pos": "29",
                    "idt": "24-07-2017",
                    "rchrg": "N",
                    "cflag": "U",
                    "inum": "9",
                    "chksum": "8aa3acd295c97aad72b174bfd98a521914e5c869608cafbc1f07ed1472f269ca"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "ctin": "29AAXFM9455A1ZO",
            "cfs": "Y",
            "inv": [{
                "itms": [{
                    "num": 1,
                    "itc": {
                        "elg": "ip",
                        "tx_c": 385.56,
                        "tx_s": 385.56
                    },
                    "itm_det": {
                        "samt": 385.56,
                        "rt": 28,
                        "txval": 2754,
                        "camt": 385.56
                    }
                }],
                "val": 3526,
                "inv_typ": "R",
                "flag": "N",
                "updby": "S",
                "pos": "29",
                "idt": "28-07-2017",
                "rchrg": "N",
                "cflag": "U",
                "inum": "1718/508",
                "chksum": "03bbeb45778a4ea3019d7c7a2a71d2d3e48ed2433fe4e027606fb2dba59d4a64"
            }]
        },
        {
            "ctin": "29AAACE3688F1ZG",
            "cfs": "Y",
            "inv": [{
                    "itms": [{
                        "num": 1,
                        "itc": {
                            "elg": "ip",
                            "tx_c": 882.42,
                            "tx_s": 882.42
                        },
                        "itm_det": {
                            "samt": 882.42,
                            "rt": 28,
                            "txval": 6303,
                            "camt": 882.42
                        }
                    }],
                    "val": 8068,
                    "inv_typ": "R",
                    "flag": "N",
                    "updby": "S",
                    "pos": "29",
                    "idt": "19-07-2017",
                    "rchrg": "N",
                    "cflag": "U",
                    "inum": "EEPLB1718/1208",
                    "chksum": "7afd73b6b9aeada9113b54ec7151ba08fb2ca0a8e23fc89ac3126d8c9722ff66"
                },
                {
                    "itms": [{
                        "num": 1,
                        "itc": {
                            "elg": "ip",
                            "tx_c": 1137.08,
                            "tx_s": 1137.08
                        },
                        "itm_det": {
                            "samt": 1137.08,
                            "rt": 28,
                            "txval": 8122,
                            "camt": 1137.08
                        }
                    }],
                    "val": 10396,
                    "inv_typ": "R",
                    "flag": "N",
                    "updby": "S",
                    "pos": "29",
                    "idt": "24-07-2017",
                    "rchrg": "N",
                    "cflag": "U",
                    "inum": "EEPLB1718/1267",
                    "chksum": "5079a0d6c289ee0077fb2fd167fd88691f2a1557cff0d2789912bc9460d35f98"
                },
                {
                    "itms": [{
                        "num": 1,
                        "itc": {
                            "elg": "ip",
                            "tx_c": 549.36,
                            "tx_s": 549.36
                        },
                        "itm_det": {
                            "samt": 549.36,
                            "rt": 28,
                            "txval": 3924,
                            "camt": 549.36
                        }
                    }],
                    "val": 5023,
                    "inv_typ": "R",
                    "flag": "N",
                    "updby": "S",
                    "pos": "29",
                    "idt": "26-07-2017",
                    "rchrg": "N",
                    "cflag": "U",
                    "inum": "EEPLB1718/1289",
                    "chksum": "6480112156a400f0ca2380c577c7a59c7a4321da5e845f577be992b6324219ee"
                },
                {
                    "itms": [{
                        "num": 1,
                        "itc": {
                            "elg": "ip",
                            "tx_c": 888.16,
                            "tx_s": 888.16
                        },
                        "itm_det": {
                            "samt": 888.16,
                            "rt": 28,
                            "txval": 6344,
                            "camt": 888.16
                        }
                    }],
                    "val": 8120,
                    "inv_typ": "R",
                    "flag": "N",
                    "updby": "S",
                    "pos": "29",
                    "idt": "28-07-2017",
                    "rchrg": "N",
                    "cflag": "U",
                    "inum": "EEPLB1718/1322",
                    "chksum": "4d0f2654fd0c1c1bf0c1a2fceb18adeb74123ec62d2556f569f22372f9ece4e1"
                },
                {
                    "itms": [{
                        "num": 1,
                        "itc": {
                            "elg": "ip",
                            "tx_c": 602.98,
                            "tx_s": 602.98
                        },
                        "itm_det": {
                            "samt": 602.98,
                            "rt": 28,
                            "txval": 4307,
                            "camt": 602.98
                        }
                    }],
                    "val": 5513,
                    "inv_typ": "R",
                    "flag": "N",
                    "updby": "S",
                    "pos": "29",
                    "idt": "29-07-2017",
                    "rchrg": "N",
                    "cflag": "U",
                    "inum": "EEPLB1718/1323",
                    "chksum": "a3f0dba67b1352affd1877d45a9eabfe99a60f67cda693881c24ab1f2c967a6d"
                },
                {
                    "itms": [{
                        "num": 1,
                        "itc": {
                            "elg": "ip",
                            "tx_c": 939.68,
                            "tx_s": 939.68
                        },
                        "itm_det": {
                            "samt": 939.68,
                            "rt": 28,
                            "txval": 6712,
                            "camt": 939.68
                        }
                    }],
                    "val": 8591,
                    "inv_typ": "R",
                    "flag": "N",
                    "updby": "S",
                    "pos": "29",
                    "idt": "29-07-2017",
                    "rchrg": "N",
                    "cflag": "U",
                    "inum": "EEPLB1718/1324",
                    "chksum": "77f0c25a4b574129b882395d5a79955cfe23c80cd7edf9accef0afd798696478"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
 }
```

This is my PHP code. All the tables are connected with foreign keys.

```
<?php
$jsondata = file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);

$data = json_decode($jsondata, true);
//$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT into itc(ctin, cfs, num, tx_cs, elg, tx_i, tx_c, tx_s, samt, csamt, rt, txval, camt, iamt, val, inv_typ, flag, updby, pos, idt, rchrg, cflag, inum, chksum) values(: ctin,: cfs,: num,: tx_cs,: elg,: tx_i,: tx_c,: tx_s,: samt,: csamt,: rt,: txval,: camt,: iamt,: val,: inv_typ,: flag,: updby,: pos,: idt,: rchrg,: cflag,: inum,: chksum)");

$gstin = $data['gstin'];
$fp = $data['fp'];
$stmt = "INSERT INTO gstin (gstin, fp) VALUES('$gstin', '$fp')";

mysqli_query($conn, $stmt);

foreach ($data['b2b'] as $row1) {
    $ctin = $row1['ctin'];
    $cfs = $row1['cfs'];

    $gst_id = '';

    $sql = "SELECT `auto_increment` as LastID FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
    WHERE table_name = 'gstin'
    ";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    // if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

        //if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            //$lclId = intval($row["LastID"]) - 1 + intval('1');
            //$gst_id = 'BU-'.$lclId  ;
            //echo $row["LastID"];
        //}
    //} else {
    // }

    $gst_id = intval($row["LastID"]) - 1;

    //echo $gst_id;
    //$lclDeptCode = 'DS-01';
    //$gst_id = $lclId  ;
    //echo $row["LastID"];
}


$stmt = "INSERT INTO b2b (ctin, cfs, gst_id) VALUES('$ctin', '$cfs', '$gst_id')";

mysqli_query($conn, $stmt);

foreach ($row1['inv'] as $row3) {
    $val = $row3['val'];
    $inv_typ = $row3['inv_typ'];
    $flag = $row3['flag'];
    $updby = $row3['updby'];
    $pos = $row3['pos'];
    $idt = $row3['idt'];
    $rchrg = $row3['rchrg'];
    $cflag = $row3['cflag'];
    $inum = $row3['inum'];
    $chksum = $row3['chksum'];

    $b_id = '';
    $sql = "SELECT `auto_increment` as LastID FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
    WHERE table_name = 'b2b'";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $b_id = intval($row["LastID"]) - 1;
    }

    $stmt = "INSERT INTO inv (val, inv_typ, flag, updby, pos, idt, rchrg, cflag, inum, chksum, b_id)
    VALUES('$val', '$inv_typ', '$flag', '$updby', '$pos', '$idt', '$rchrg', '$cflag', '$inum', '$chksum', '$b_id')";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $stmt);

    foreach($row1['inv'][0]['itms'] as $row2) {
        // echo $row2;
        // print_r($row2);
        $tx_cs = $row2['itc']['tx_cs'];
        $elg = $row2['itc']['elg'];
        $tx_i = $row2['itc']['tx_i'];
        $tx_c = $row2['itc']['tx_c'];
        $tx_s = $row2['itc']['tx_s'];
        $samt = $row2['itm_det']['samt'];
        $csamt = $row2['itm_det']['csamt'];
        $rt = $row2['itm_det']['rt'];
        $txval = $row2['itm_det']['txval'];
        $camt = $row2['itm_det']['camt'];
        $iamt = $row2['itm_det']['iamt'];

        $inv_id = '';
        $sql = "SELECT `auto_increment` as LastID FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE table_name = 'inv'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

        if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        //}
        //if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            $inv_id = intval($row["LastID"]) - 1;
        }

        $stmt = "INSERT INTO itms (tx_cs, elg, tx_i, tx_c, tx_s, samt, csamt, rt, txval, camt, iamt, inv_id)
        VALUES('$tx_cs', '$elg', '$tx_i', '$tx_c', '$tx_s', '$samt', '$csamt', '$rt', '$txval', '$camt', '$iamt', '$inv_id')";

        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $stmt);
    }
}
}
```

I am getting duplicate values in columns `tx_i, tx_c, tx_i`.
Is there an alternative way to access values and I am getting undefined index `tx_i` in `itms` array even though the key is present.

Comment: Use json_encode and var_dump to understand the structure of the object.

Comment: I have done but getting duplicate values

Comment: my problem is only for itms array not for other arrays

Comment: What's the output of var_dump(json_decode($json)); ? (Please add it to your question and i'll do my best to help you)

Comment: Please show your php code.

Comment: php code end of the json

Comment: First decode JSON string using json_decode(), then access as key value.

Comment: I have Updated my php code

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php


$jsondata = file_get_contents('file.json');

$data = json_decode($jsondata, true);

echo'<pre>';


$tx_i=array();
$tx_c=array();
$tx_s=array();
foreach($data['b2b'] as $row){


    (isset($row['inv'][0]['itms'][0]['itc']['tx_i'])) ? $tx_i[]=$row['inv'][0]['itms'][0]['itc']['tx_i'] : null;
    (isset($row['inv'][0]['itms'][0]['itc']['tx_s'])) ? $tx_s[]=$row['inv'][0]['itms'][0]['itc']['tx_s'] : null;
    (isset($row['inv'][0]['itms'][0]['itc']['tx_c'])) ? $tx_c[]=$row['inv'][0]['itms'][0]['itc']['tx_c'] : null;
}

print_r($tx_i);
print_r($tx_s);
print_r($tx_c);
```

This code checks if the `tx_i , tx_s , tx_c` values exist and if they do it puts each of them in a new array.

The output is :

```
Array
(
    [0] => 112.5
)
Array
(
    [0] => 171.59
    [1] => 20
    [2] => 329
    [3] => 114.39
    [4] => 385.56
    [5] => 882.42
)
Array
(
    [0] => 171.59
    [1] => 20
    [2] => 329
    [3] => 114.39
    [4] => 385.56
    [5] => 882.42
)
```

The "main" issue was that in the same path you have the variables you want and sometimes they don't exist. So in one array you may have tx_i and in the next array have tx_c in it's position so you need to see first if they are set.

Comment: bro, getting Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array

Comment: Where do you get this error and what php version do you have?

Comment: here, (isset($row['inv'][0]['itms'][0]['itc']['tx_i'])) ? $tx_i[]=$row['inv'][0]['itms'][0]['itc']['tx_i'] : null; for all 3   and again getting duplicate values are inserted.

Comment: https://www.abeautifulsite.net/how-to-use-the-php-ternary-operator

Propably  you are having a php version older than 5.3. I provide you the manual to convert it to a normal if/else it's easy. Don't forget the isset that does the trick do get the output i provided.

Comment: If your php version is more than 5.3 make sure that in your code you include this : 
`$tx_i=array();`
`$tx_c=array();`
`$tx_s=array();`

That is 99% the reason a scala error appears, that an array is not "defined" as an array. This will solve your error.

Comment: PHP Version 5.5.19 this is my php version

Comment: Did you define the arrays before you use them as i saw you in the above comment? like i define them in my code?

Comment: bro, if the inv contains more number of itms inside inv that time foreach looping only the first itc and itm_det that is not going deeply

Comment: My code will go to position 0 where the itc values are. Is there any chance that itc values exist also in other parts of your json? Basically my code follows a specific path that i saw that are the values you want.

Comment: Then what is the problem. can you saw me which part fails and where it fails?

Comment: i will share my database pic

Comment: can I use foreach loop bracket separately

Comment: you mean use $data instead of $data['b2b'] ?

Comment: same way but 1st foreach loop ends before the next foreach loop start

Comment: In my code i have 1 foreach loop to parse through your json. But you can try it. This part of my code works in order to get the values you want from your json so moving forward to your code you have to see how you insert those values in the db. For sure you will need a loop because we are talking about arrays.